# How to convert timezone abbreviation to long Form in react js Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to get current time and convert abbreviation **IST** to **Indian Standard Time**

```
var d = (new Date()).toTimeString();
```

in above code i got the output with current date **12:55:34 GMT+0530 (IST)** 
now how to convert IST to Indian Standard Time

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Sample code would help people guide you in the right direction.

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: Notice my answer
You receive the output you requested

Answer (score 0):

```
let d = new Date(2019, 11, 24, 12, 25, 00, 0);;

let dStr=d.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"})
new Date(dStr).toISOString()
```

output

```
"2019-12-24T13:55:00.000Z"
```

[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

> timeZone
> The time zone to use. The only value implementations must recognize is "UTC"; the default is the runtime's default time zone. Implementations may also recognize the time zone names of the IANA time zone database, such as "Asia/Shanghai", "Asia/Kolkata", "America/New_York".

Comment: it returns me the current date only i want this **12:55:34 GMT+0530 (Indian Standard Time)**

Comment: i tried it give me this ouput `2019-12-24T17:55:34.000Z` :( i want only 'Indian Standard Time' in return

Comment: still same output :(